# Go for ajax, websockets or something else for asynchronous page loading on django

Tags: ajax, django, asynchronous, websocket

I am working on a django web-app.

I have a query that takes quite some time to get fetched and I want the output to be visible to my user.

I am doubting about going for Ajax or Websockets for asynchronous loading of the data. Or might there be something else to use in this case.

**Websockets:**

I know Websockets can do realtime stuff and update the page.

However, they can only process serialised content.

So does this means when I go for websockets that I am stuck with Json files in my HTML-environment, no easy pagination, no easy use of django templates?

**Ajax:**

Ajax can do requests from the page in an "asynchronous" way, so no reload of the page required.

But: if my query takes longer then the timeout of my app (heroku timeout of 30 seconds, not changeable), will the ajax request also timeout in 30 seconds of have more time to get completed?

**alternatives?**

Any alternatives to deal with this asynchronous page loading behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A civil enigneering approach would be to try those thins out first which you can try easyly. To set up some testing ajax is done within a few lines. For one of my longer running ajax requests i use a so called web worker. Those will run completely asynchronous and tell that they are ready by events. They have the benefit that your app will be completely responsive. Thy just "yell" by the return  event that they are ready :)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Have fun Thomas